# Search Recursively for a value provided within a set directory

Tags: java, user-interface, search, directory

I'm trying to find a string within the directory `C:\` which is currently hardcoded. Within this `C:\` directory, I'm looking to recursively find the inputted string (inputString) within the root/and subdirectories and finally output the names of the files containing those strings.

I hope the above clarifies my initial question

I currently have **assess.java**:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/* Notes: Event - user clicking button, moving mouse
 *  EventHandler - code that response to users action
 * 
 */

class assess {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        assesshelper assessment1 = new assesshelper();
        assessment1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        assessment1.setSize(500,500); // set size of window
        assessment1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and 
**assesshelper.java**

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout; // orientation of screen
import javax.swing.JFrame; // JFrame all basic windows features (min/maximize), title
import javax.swing.JTextField; // Typing text
import javax.swing.JLabel; // output text / images


public class assesshelper extends JFrame {

    private JLabel item1;

    private JTextField theUrl;

    public assesshelper(){ // anything within assesshelper is within window
        super("Assess"); // title of window
        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // gives us default label

        //item1
        item1 = new JLabel("Welcome!");
        add(item1); // add item1 to the screen


        String setDir = "C:/";
        JTextField inputString = new JTextField();

        inputString.setText("ENTER DIR TO PROCESS");
        /// BEGIN SEARCHING FOR INPUTTED STRING HERE WITHIN ROOT/SUBDIRECTORIES, OUTPUT FILE NAMES CONTAINING STRING

        add(inputString);

    }

}
```

How do I recursively search for the value of `inputString` within the directory set by setDir?

(Java-newbie here -- please keep it constructive)

Comment: Are you searching for a file name or the file contents??

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's very vague from his question, but looking at his source there is a comment that says `output file names containing string`.

Comment: I'm searching the file contents for the words entered in the inputString var

Comment: I've modified my original question to make the question for concrete with what I'm asking.

Comment: @CodeTalk In that case, see my edit.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee Your recursive algorithm is correct and there's nothing wrong with it, just feeling the full spec ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good thing you did, for I found out I had misunderstood the question :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you are new, this is a simple recursive solution (in no means the most efficient though):

```
public static final FileFilter DIRS = new FileFilter() {

  public boolean accept(File file) {
    return file.isDirectory();
  }

};

public static final FileFilter FILES = new FileFilter() {

  public boolean accept(File file) {
    return file.isFile();
  }

}

public void walkTree(File start) throws IOException {

  File[] dirs = start.listFiles(DIRS);
  File[] files = start.listFiles(FILES);

  for (File file : files) {
    if (file.canRead()) {
      if (readAndCheck(file, "string")) {
        // Do Whatever
      }
    }
  }

  for (File dir : dirs) {
    walkTree(dir);
  }

}

public boolean readAndCheck(File file, String string) throws IOException {

  BufferedReader br = null;
  StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

  try {

    // If line separators matter in your pattern, consider reading every character
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      total.append(line);
    }

  } finally {
    if (br != null) {
      br.close();
    }
  }

  return total.toString().contains(string);

}
```

*Note:* There may be a couple syntax errors as I wrote this in the answerbox.

---

Also, you're going to have to launch this on a new Thread, preferably using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html):

Answer (score 0):

Taking LanguagesNamedAfterCofee answer into account, you can read files relatively easily...

```
public void searchFile(File file, String value) throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {

        fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int line = 1;
        String text = null;
        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (text.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.println("found " + text + " in " + file + " @ [" + line + ":" + text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) + "]");
            }
            line++;
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            fr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Now this example will only read text files (it will read binary files, but the usefulness is negotiable) and print out the file and line where the value was found.

Ideally, you could pass this information back to the client via some kind of callback method, model or collect the information for later use...

Comment: Note that closing `BufferedReader` will close the underlying `FileReader` as well, so you don't have to explicitly close it yourself.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee Note paranoia (yes you are right, but I'm paranoid about ANY stream not doing the right thing ;))

Comment: Why will this only read in text files? Can I somehow add an array to it listing extensions e.g. 0=>'.jsp' 1=>'.java'2='.php' ... etc ? that you could show me how??

Comment: It will read any file, but if you read a binary file (such as `png`) the meaning of any search results is questionable. You could take a look at [File#listFiles(FileFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) for more information on how to filter directory listings

Comment: The above code will read anything, how meaningful it is based on the file content will be questionable.